# Error of 'failed to push some refs' pushing to remote repo on Digital Ocean

Tags: git, deployment, web-deployment, virtualhost, digital-ocean

I'm following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps) DO tutorial 'Set Up Automatic Deployment with Git' with one of my virtual hosts.  When trying to push to the Remote repo locally with the command `git push live master`

I receive:

```
Counting objects: 1195, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1064/1064), done.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://USER@IP/var/repo/WEBSITE
t.git'
```

I think it may be a problem with permissions as I had to use sudo in a couple of the steps or it is maybe a novice's mistake. Any guidance to troubleshoot or a point in the right direction this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The user that's pushing to the `/var/repo/awesome_repo.git` doesn't has any permissions in that path and is an step not covered during the tutorial.

To solve this what I did was:

`sudo chown -R git_user:git_user /var/repo/awesome_repo.git/`

Replace the *git_user* with the username you use to push via ssh.